# getImageData memory leak issue in window's chrome browser : javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

i am getting memory leak issue on getImageData()[api provided by javascript] when using in a loop  for fething the data from canvas in Window 7's chrome browser, it increase chrome memory on each travel on getImageData() api, so after some time  when default chrome memory full its being crased.if any one know any workarround of this please suggest.

used code:

```
this.surface.drawImage(this.st1, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); 
var data = this.surface.getImageData(0,0, this.canvas.width, 
this.canvas.height);
this.timer = setTimeout(this.paint, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `this` belongs to `owner` of the method on which it is called.

In `setTimeout`, `this` belongs to window as `setTimeout` is method of `window` => `window.setTimeout`

> Use `.bind()`

Try this:

```js
this.surface.drawImage(this.st1, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); 
var data = this.surface.getImageData(0,0, this.canvas.width, 
this.canvas.height);
this.timer = setTimeout(paint.bind(this), 500);
```

Comment: tried(.bind()) your solution however its still incresing chrome memory continiously:Not working pls suggest if any thing i am missing.

Comment: also why you create var _this=this; but you are not using it.

Comment: Can you share the dimension of the image file you are drawing on the canvas ?

Comment: canvas :   width: 1024  height: 786 , maxFrameRate:25

Comment: pls refer this sample and click on top button for execution:    https://jsfiddle.net/dvu9z6td/   so FYI issue is only on window 7 chrome browser

Comment: you can check it on: open task manger and go to memory and see ir increasing

Comment: It is not `getImageData` but `which` loop which is causing issues...Whay do you need that ? While loop is synchronous and it will halt the execution of the next line..and will disturb user experience...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105118/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-sram).